# Compilation fails with "expected expression before '{' token"

Tags: c, macros, initialization, variable-assignment

I'm trying to initialize `ip_addr` in a clean way and the library is giving me the `IPADDR4_INIT` macro but it seems that I don't use it properly.

Here is the extracted issue:

```
#include "stdint.h"

struct ip4_addr {
  uint32_t addr;
};

typedef struct ip4_addr ip_addr_t;

#define IPADDR4_INIT(u32val)                    { u32val }

int main()
{
  ip_addr_t ip_addr;
  uint32_t u32val = 0xC0A80001;

  ip_addr = IPADDR4_INIT(u32val);

  return 0;
}
```

Compilation fails returning me this:

```
9:49: error: expected expression before '{' token
```

Comment: What's this macro supposedly good for?

Comment: It's a macro from the LwIP libray : https://www.nongnu.org/lwip/2_1_x/ip__addr_8h.html

Comment: Yuck. Defining your own "secret macro language" is a cardinal sin. Whoever wrote that lib needs a lesson in how to write inline functions. Probably doesn't even need to inline, smells like pre-mature optimization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
ip_addr = IPADDR4_INIT(u32val);
```

Expands to:

```
ip_addr = { u32val };
```

Which is not valid syntax for an assignment.  You either need to do this on initialization:

```
uint32_t u32val = 0xC0A80001;
ip_addr_t  ip_addr = IPADDR4_INIT(u32val);
```

Or to change the macro to compound literal syntax which does allow you to do the assignment:

```
#define IPADDR4_INIT(u32val)    (ip_addr_t){ u32val }
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use a brace enclosed initializer to **assign** a value to a variable of type struct, you have to use it in **initialization** syntax.

Something like

```
 ip_addr_t ip_addr = IPADDR4_INIT(u32val);
```

should do.

Alternatively, you have to use a [compound literal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax#Compound_literals), something like

```
 ip_addr_t ip_addr = (ip_addr_t ) IPADDR4_INIT(u32val);
```

or, change the macro definition to contain one:

```
 #define IPADDR4_INIT(u32val)    (ip_addr_t){ u32val }
```

Comment: Yes.  Or to form a compound literal, which you can use in an assignment.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Absolutely.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler is telling you that the expanded macro isn't valid C. It becomes this:

`ip_addr = { u32val };`.

You can only *initialize* a struct like that, not *assign* to one.

Not sure what you are trying to do here, set one struct member? Doesn't make much sense to do that through a macro, but if you simply must use macros for some reason, then you could use a *compound literal*:

```
#define IPADDR4_INIT(u32val)  (ip_addr_t){ .addr = (u32val) }
```